# NGINX shows script code instead of execute

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a troble with NGINX that makes me insane. I have Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on VirtualBox. I installed NGINX-MYSQL-PHP following these instructions:

1. install **php5-fpm**;
2. set **cgi.fix_pathinfo=0** in */etc/php5/fpm/php.ini*;
3. set **listen = var/run/php5-fpm.sock** in */etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*

Then I set in */etc/nginx/sites-available/default*:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Both *localhost* and *info.php* are executed properly. Now i want to set up a local website and try to make some redirect. So I created a new folder in */usr/share/nginx/www* called *mywebsite*, put a *index.php* inside with a echo instruction, a php script i make redirect to, added a new config file in *sites-available* and a link to that in *sites-enabled*, and disable  *application/octet-stream* in *nginx.conf* in order to avoid to downloading the script file. So i set my new config file as following:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/mysite;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.mysite.com;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/location/([0-9]+)/device/([0-9]+)/senseddata/$ /senseddata.php break;
        rewrite ^/location/([0-9]+)/device/([0-9]+)/senseddata/lasthour/$ /senseddata.php break;
        rewrite ^/location/([0-9]+)/device/([0-9]+)/senseddata/daily/$ /senseddata.php break;
      }
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
       try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
   }
}
```

So what happened after all? Index.php is executed properly. Rewrite is done well but the script is not executed. I only see the entire code i wrote displayed in the browser. What's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your nginx works stand alone or reverse proxy with apache ? Looks like your nginx is not having a valid php handler

Comment: what do you get when you run `sudo service php5-fpm status` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. NGINX works alone and the php5-fpm status is running. By the way, I solved the problem writing LAST insted of BREAK in rewrite lines. I don't know the difference between the two words (maybe someone could explain) but it fix the problem. And it's good. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have same problem, and my config file same as @pasha-proton mentioned in his answer, still not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the opening tags in your PHP-files. If you use `<?` instead of `<?php` and the [short tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) is not available, the PHP-code will not be parsed and you will see the source.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;` to `location ~ \.php$` and restart nginx.

Example from my config

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I have same problem, and my config file same as you mention, still not working